# Java iso extracting using loopy

Tags: java, iso

I want to create a project to burn operating system images to CDs or DVDs
I've searched a little and found that "loopy" is the right tool  for doing this
I've downloaded the jar file but I don't know how to use it in my project

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Tip: Don't make people who look at your question search all info themselves. Link to "loopy" and tell them what you tried and what your environment is. For example Eclipse on Windows or IntelliJ Idea on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

To use loopy with VFS, simply include the jar on the classpath and access your iso file using the following URL format: iso:/path/to/file.iso.